# Insert into tables based on updating list (table)

Tags: sql-server

Ive been struggling with this one for a while and appreciate any help.
I have a table that continuously get updated with a list of table names (same table can occure several times) that has been updated with new data recently in Database 1.

**I want to create a query that checks this update list and inserts the data from updated tables in Database 1, into corresponding tables in Database 2. And loops through until the end of the list.**

The list can look like this:

```
ID                          Table         TimeStamp   
-----------------------     --------      -----------------------
0313778E-CB68-E811-910D     Customer      2018-07-10 13:27:28.567  
0313778E-CB68-E811-910D     Customer      2018-07-10 13:28:58.010  
194DD17A-CE68-E811-910D     Order         2018-07-10 13:27:28.567   
0EBB391D-126B-E811-910D     Product       2018-07-10 13:28:58.010      
4AAE33A5-CE68-E811-910D     Customer      2018-07-10 13:27:28.567     
DFA2A68C-056B-E811-910D     Order         2018-07-10 13:28:58.010     
C2CFECB6-CE68-E811-910D     Employee      2018-07-10 13:27:28.583
```

To make it worse, the tables in Database 2 don't have same amount of columns as Database 1. 
Ive been working on both MERGE and Cursor, as well as dynamic SQL. Im new to these so keep getting stuck. I think dynamic SQL + CURSOR is the best way to go. All of this will result in a stored procedure. Maybe there is a better way of doing it? Anyway, this is what I have:

```
Declare @Source_TableName_Column --this one contains the Database 1 tables as well as the correct columns needed to fill matching table in Database 2.
Declare @InsertInto NVARCHAR(MAX), 
@TargetTable NVARCHAR(MAX)='Select name from Database2.sys.all_objects',   --list of tables I have in Database 2
@Columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Select name from Database2.sys.all_columns',  --list of columns I have in Database 2 (same names as it is in SourceTable in Database 1)
; 

DECLARE TableInsert CURSOR FOR
SELECT distinct SourceTableName from Database3.dbo.UpdateTableList
OPEN TableInsert

FETCH NEXT FROM TableInsert
INTO @TableName

--LOOP
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
   BEGIN
   SET @InsertInto = 'insert into Database2.dbo.'+@TargetTable+' '+(@Columns)+' values'+(....)+'' --not sure how to do this variable where i get all the results from SourceTable matching columns in TargetTable in database 2

        FETCH NEXT FROM TableInsert
        INTO @TableName       
   END
        --CLOSE CURSOR
        CLOSE TableInsert
        DEALLOCATE TableInsert
```

Comment: Will the table in database 1 contain the same amount of records as database 2? What you're trying to do is quite complex but it would be interesting to know why as there could be an alternative solution.

Comment: Not initially. Database 1 gets updated from an external source. Database 2 tables should be filled up with the same data that has "arrived" in Database 1 tables. Just that Database 2 tables has fewer columns. But the idea is to have a script that fills in the same records, yes.

Comment: Spamming, sorry. If I want all the records, is there a simpler way you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a solution that works for me. Some names I have changed here to better fit my description above. I think they are correct, will look through it later and correct it if wrong =)

*I am, however,* a bit unsure about the delete statement further down in the code.
I have a TempTable based on the update list. I want to delete the rows in the update list after Ive inserted into tables. I have one with two 'where field IN (corresponding field in TempTable' clauses and another one with a 'delete from ... where exists (tempTable). Temptable has two columns but update list has three in total. Whichever is fastest/best?

```
DECLARE @InsertInto NVARCHAR(MAX); 
DECLARE @SourceID NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @TableAttribute NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SourceViewName NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @TargetTable NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SourceTableName NVARCHAR(MAX);

/*-------Create temp table to be used in cursor-------*/
Declare @SQL_TempTable_Insert NVARCHAR(MAX);
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Cursor_TempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Cursor_TempTable
    CREATE TABLE #Cursor_TempTable (
    SourceEntity NVARCHAR(MAX)  )

/*-------variable to be used in insert step below-------*/
SET @SQL_TempTable_Insert = 'SELECT SourceLogicalName FROM DataBaseC.dbo.REF_ENTITIES_SYNC group by SourceLogicalName'

/*-------Insert into temp table-------*/
INSERT INTO #Cursor_TempTable EXECUTE (@SQL_TempTable_Insert)



/*-------Create temp table from NeworUpdate table-------*/
Declare @SQL_TempTable_NewOrUpdated NVARCHAR(MAX);
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.. #TempTable_NewOrUpdated') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE  #TempTable_NewOrUpdated
    CREATE TABLE #TempTable_NewOrUpdated (
    [ID] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [TimeStamp] DATETIME ) 

/*-------variable to be used in insert step below in NewOrUpdate temp table-------*/
SET @SQL_TempTable_NewOrUpdated = 'SELECT ID, TimeStamp FROM DataBaseC.dbo.[REF_POSTS_NewOrUpdated] group by ID, TimeStamp'

/*-------Insert into NewOrUpdate temp table-------*/
INSERT INTO #TempTable_NewOrUpdated EXECUTE (@SQL_TempTable_NewOrUpdated)




/*-------Cursor segment-------*/
DECLARE EntitiesInsert CURSOR FOR
 SELECT SourceEntity FROM #Cursor_TempTable
OPEN EntitiesInsert
FETCH NEXT FROM EntitiesInsert
INTO @TargetTable 
--LOOP
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
   BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
     BEGIN TRAN

SET @SourceViewName = (select SourceName from DataBaseC.dbo.REF_ENTITIES_SYNC where Targetname = @TargetTable);
SET @SourceTableName = (select SourceTableName from DataBaseC.dbo.REF_ENTITIES_SYNC where Targetname = @TargetTable);
SET @TableAttribute = stuff(( select ', ' +char(10)+ ac.[name] from DataBaseB.sys.all_columns ac 
                              inner join DataBaseB.sys.all_objects ao on ao.object_id=ac.object_id
                              where ao.name = @TargetTable and ac.name not in ('ValidFrom','ValidTo')
                              FOR XML PATH('')
                              ), 1, 1, '')

--Finds DatabaseA table's Primary Key 
SET @SourceID =  (select c.name
 from sys.index_columns ic
 inner join sys.columns c on ic.object_id = c.object_id and ic.column_id = c.column_id
 inner join sys.indexes i on ic.object_id = i.object_id and ic.index_id = i.index_id
 inner join sys.tables t on i.object_id = t.object_id
 inner join sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
 where i.is_primary_key= 1 and t.name = @SourceTableName);

SET @InsertInto = 'INSERT INTO DataBaseB.dbo.'+@TargetTable+' ('+@TableAttribute+') 
SELECT '+@TableAttribute+' FROM DataBaseA.dbo.'+@SourceViewName+'  
where '+@SourceID+' in (select nu.ID from DataBaseC.Inno.REF_ENTITIES_SYNC sync inner join #TempTable_NewOrUpdated nu on nu.SourceEntity = sync.TargetName where sync.TargetName = '''+@TargetTable+''' group by nu.ID )' 
EXEC sp_sqlexec @insertInto


--Delete the records from [DataBaseC].[dbo].[REF_POSTS_NewOrUpdated] that we have inserted.
--DELETE FROM [DataBaseC].[dbo].[REF_POSTS_NewOrUpdated]
--  WHERE ID = (select [ID] from #TempTable_NewOrUpdated)
--  AND TimeStamp = (select [Timestamp] from #TempTable_NewOrUpdated)  
----alt2
--DELETE FROM [DataBaseC].[dbo].[REF_POSTS_NewOrUpdated]
--  where exists (select * from #TempTable_NewOrUpdated)


--End TRAN
  COMMIT
--End TRY
  END TRY

    --Catch possible errors
        BEGIN CATCH

            --IF there is an open transaction then roll back and print error messages.
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

            DECLARE @ErrorNumber INT = ERROR_NUMBER();
            DECLARE @ErrorLine INT = ERROR_LINE();
            DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE();
            DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY();
            DECLARE @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE();

            PRINT 'Actual error number: ' + CAST(@ErrorNumber AS VARCHAR(10));
            PRINT 'Actual line number: ' + CAST(@ErrorLine AS VARCHAR(10));
            PRINT 'Actual error message: ' + CAST(@ErrorMessage AS VARCHAR(MAX));
            PRINT 'Actual error Severity: ' + CAST(@ErrorSeverity AS VARCHAR(MAX));             
            PRINT 'Actual error State: ' + CAST(@ErrorState AS VARCHAR(MAX));

        END CATCH

FETCH NEXT FROM EntitiesInsert
INTO @TargetTable      
END
CLOSE EntitiesInsert
DEALLOCATE EntitiesInsert

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

This is complex. I would approach it in a simpler fashion than what you are doing. I’d do it your way if scenario involved destination tables with the same schema, but numerous columns, which does not seem to be the case with you. 
Here’s what i’d do.

Open cur1
Fetch next from cur1 into @tablename ....

While @@fetchstatus = 0
Begin

If @@tablename= ‘tbl1’
Begin
 Insert into database2.dbo.tbl2 values
Select ... from database1.dbo.table1 where ..
End

If @@tablename = ‘tblx’
And so on

Fetch next from cur1 into ...
End

Comment: Thanks, will look into this. They don't look quite the same no. You could see it as this: Target Tables in Database 2 is a 'cola light' version of the Source Tables in Database 1. Same but just scaled off column wise

Comment: Thanks. This loops one table at a time yes? I thought of that too, but the goal is to have it dynamically. So that when a new table is added in Database 1 (Source Tables) it will be created automatically in Database 2, a Stored Procedure that does this I have already.

Comment: Is see. In that case, have a variable to construct the values portion of the insert query and then append it to the @insertInto to create final complete insert query in the loop. To loop through the columns dynamically to construct the values string , you may have to use another cursor or a while loop within your existing cursor . And then use sp_executesql or exec(<dynamic sql string>) to run it.

Comment: I was thinking about a cursor within another cursor just as you said. But Im having a difficult time wrapping it around in my head. Im new to cursor and dynamic SQL =). I also been thinking a Temp Table with SourceTable column list and all the table's columns in it (two columns in the temp table. Do you think you can aid me in the cursor building?
And that variable you suggest should be something like:SET @_ColumnData = 'select @_Columns from @_SourceTables'? Where Columns are a list of the columns i need and @_SourceTables are  a list of the tables to take data from?